# How to properly implement MouseInputListener in custom JComponent

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I'm trying to implement some mouseListener functionality to a custom component I built. However, I'm running into some roadblocks getting it to work. Here is the code for the custom JComponent.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;

import org.w3c.dom.events.MouseEvent;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class PhotoComponent extends JComponent implements MouseInputListener{
    
    private ImageIcon pic;
    Boolean flipped = false;

    public PhotoComponent(){

    }

    public PhotoComponent(ImageIcon p){
        pic=p;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        if(pic==null){
            return new Dimension(0,0);
        }
        return new Dimension(pic.getIconWidth(), pic.getIconHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        if (flipped==false){
            pic.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
        }

        if (flipped==true){
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, pic.getIconWidth(), pic.getIconHeight());
            g.fillRect(0,0, pic.getIconWidth(), pic.getIconHeight());
        }
    

    }

    
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        if(e.getClickCount()==2){
            flipped=!flipped;
            repaint();
            jl.settext("hi");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        //lol
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        //lol
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        //lol
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
        //lol
    }


}
```

The goal is to switch between the real image and an all-white version of it with a double click of the mouse. The component will be utilized in this code below.

```
public class Base extends JFrame {
    private JPanel radio, buttons, tags, container, statusContainer;
    private JScrollPane mainScroll;
    private JButton next, prev, delete;
    private JMenuBar jmb;
    private JMenu file, view;
    private JMenuItem impo;
    private JLabel jl;
    private ArrayList<PhotoComponent> picList;
    private int pos;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Base();
    }

    public Base(){
        setTitle("Placeholder");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        setResizable(true);
        
        menusAndLabels();

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void menusAndLabels(){
        jmb = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(jmb);
        file=new JMenu("File");
        statusContainer = new JPanel();
        add(statusContainer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        jmb.add(file);

        impo = new JMenuItem("Import");

        //currentPic= new PhotoComponent();
        picList= new ArrayList<PhotoComponent>(5);
        pos = 0;
        mainScroll = new JScrollPane();
        
        
        add(mainScroll);
        
        impo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent fo){
                JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser("");
                FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Graphics", "jpg","jpeg","png");
                chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
                chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
                int response = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

                if(response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                   File[] chosen = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
                    for (File f:chosen) {
                        if(f.isDirectory()){
                            File[] temp=f.listFiles();
                            for (File x:temp){;
                                ImageIcon ii =new ImageIcon(x.getAbsolutePath());
                                picList.add(new PhotoComponent(ii));
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            ImageIcon ii =new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath());
                            picList.add(new PhotoComponent(ii));
                            }
                            
                        }
                    mainScroll.setViewportView(picList.get(pos));
                    ///mainScroll.addMouseListener(picList.get(pos));
                    mainScroll.setVisible(true);
                    
                    validate();
                    }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("oops somethings wrong");
                }
                    
                }
                
            });
    

        file.add(impo);
    }
}
```

So far I get no response from my mouse listener when I try. What am I doing wrong, and how might I better implement this?

I tried adding addMouseListener(this) to the component, but it keeps giving me syntax erroes and tells me that it "requires a body". My code error keeps suggesting I add:

```
@Override
    public synchronized void addMouseListener(MouseListener l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.addMouseListener(l);
    }
```

but I'm not entirely sure what to do with that.

Comment: 1) class names should start with an upper case character 2) the class you posted is called "project" but the main() method creates a "homework" class. 3) your code is using a 3rd party API. 4) the PhotoComponent class doesn't even compile 5) post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The mouseClicked method requires a precise double click, not too close together or too far apart.  Test with mousePressed to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So far I get no response from my mouse listener

Where do you add the MouseListener to the component?

You need to add the listener to the class so it can respond to events. In your constructor you need code like:

```
addMouseListener( this );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for a working example.

Comment: I tried addMouseListener(this);  but it keeps giving me syntax erroes and tells me that it "requires a body". My code error keeps suggesting I add:

@Override
    public synchronized void addMouseListener(MouseListener l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.addMouseListener(l);
    }

but I'm not entirely sure what to do with that.

Comment: 1) I suggested where the code should be added 2) Did you read the tutorial for the working example and download the working code to see how to do this?

Comment: I read the tutorial and tried adding mouse listener to the constructor, yet I'm still not getting any output in the console.